# Why am I getting empty response on Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am preety new  to scrapy and I want to scrape this [website](https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx?type=gainers).

But I failed in first step as I tried printing response I get empty array.
Any help will be helpful.

```
import scrapy

class MarketDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "market"

    start_urls = ['https://merolagani.com/MarketSummary.aspx?type=gainers']

    items = []

    def parse(self, response):
        items = {}
        for tr in response.xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped table-hover table-index']//tbody//tr"):

            print(tr)
```

i get response as [] is the data coming from API?

Comment: The website is loaded using javascript. Read more in the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) on ways of handling dynamic content.

Comment: any way i can implemnt that i am noob :(

Comment: @NavarajPokharel try using scrapy selenium or selenium only or scrapy with splash. You will know more about scrapy with splash and with selenium  [here](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/scrapy-javascript/)